# extract html <title> tag by php

Tags: php, extract, title

i want extract TITLE tag from web site url: http://www.varzesh3.com.
I tried many ways but not.

my codes:

```html
$fp = file_get_contents($url);
        if (!$fp) 
            return null;

        $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
        if (!$res) 
            return null; 

        // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
        $title = trim($title);
        return $title;
```

```html
$tags = get_meta_tags($url); 
print_r ($tags);
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting the file properly?

Comment: I just want <title>content</titel> tag.